# Sluggish Linux VM's on Hyper-V

Tags: debian, windows-server-2012-r2, virtual-machines, hyper-v

I am experiencing very sluggish response with Linux VM's (Debian Gnome 3.30.1 64bit) running on Hyper-V on a Windows host (Server 2012 R2 64bit). Slugglish being any movement around the screen, mouse movements, button pressing, etc... The mouse cursor takes 2-3 seconds to move and update and the same with any button presses.

The VM's themselves are not running at 100% CPU and the host itself is reporting very low CPU usage (10%) yet each new VM I create seems to run slower and slower.

I'd understand if the host CPU was running high, or the VM itself, but that is not the case.

It seems with each VM I create, responsiveness gets worse, which I understand points to CPU resource, but I cannot see any indicators as to that being the case.

Responsiveness of the host seems fine, no issues. Memory usage is OK, Disk I/O isn't high... Not sure where to look.

Any pointers would be appreciated, thanks.

The host is a Dell dual processor 3.06GHz with 96GB of RAM, the guests are 4 CPU, 2GB RAM.

Comment: Well, besides running a very very outdated host? And not naming which debian version you run?

Comment: Please include the CPU model or code name. Also the type of storage: spindle RPM or solid state and what interface to the storage system.  Further, what is the load on this host, how many VMs and what are their resource allocation.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, Debian 3.30 is not supported as guest OS (take a look - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/virtualization/hyper-v/supported-debian-virtual-machines-on-hyper-v). Does the integration services installed on the VM? Try to decrease numbers of CPU from 4 to 2.